# ADMM Heuristic or rather stick to Branch and Bound?

Tags: optimization, localization, mixed-integer-programming, multigrid

I'm intending on giving  a solution to this MIQP, which should be faster than the one of solving the exact problem with GUROBI or CPLEX.(*It muss not give always the global solution!*)

The main problem is about optimization of a localization problem with a grid map, where $dx_m$, $dy_m$ and $dp_m$ are the displacement for the next iteration.

The constraint (2) guarantees that transmit power stays in the admissible range [$\overline{P}$, $\underline{P}$], while the constraints (3) and (4) assure that the update points stay in the range [$-w$,$w$], i.e in the observation area ($q_m$ and $r_m$ are respectively $dx_m$ and $dy_m$ from the previous iteration). The constraints (5) and (6) allow an update of maximal $\delta_i$. N and M are given integer numbers.

\begin{align}
&\quad\min_{s_m,dx_m,dy_m,dp_m} \ \sum_{k=1..K} (f_k+\sum_{m=1..M}a_{km}dx_m+b_{km}dy_m+c_{km}dp_m)^2 \\
&\quad \text{s.t} \ dx_m,dy_m,dp_m \in \mathbb{R} \ (1)\\ 
&\quad s_m\underline{P} \leq dp_m \leq s_m \overline{P} \  (2)\\
&\quad -s_m(w+q_m) \leq dx_m \leq-s_m(w-q_m) \ (3)\\
&\quad -s_m(w+r_m) \leq dy_m \leq-s_m(w-r_m) \ (4)\\
&\quad -s_m \delta_i \leq dx_m \leq s_m \delta_i  (5)\\
&\quad -s_m \delta_i \leq dy_m \leq s_m \delta_i \ (6)\\
&\quad s_m \in \text{{0,1}}     \ \ \ \ \ (7)\\
&\quad \sum_{m=1..M} s_m = N \ (8)
 \end{align}

I tried the ADMM  heuristic presented in the paper below. Since i couldn' transform the problem in the exact form presented there, I simpliefied the problem to a BIQP and tryed out the algorithm, which unfortunately gave very often no solution(or a very bad one).

Should I keep trying to find an ADMM heuristic which possibly offers a faster solution given a big number of grid points(equations) or stick to the branch and bound algorithms?

---

1.Reza Takapoui, Nicholas Moehle, Stephen Boyd and Alberto Bemporad :
   **A simple effective heuristic for embedded mixed-integer quadratic programming**